# how to use " a few days"?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure whether this sentence is correct or not ?

> Thank you for helping me to fix the computer for a few day.

Can you tell me how to correctly use **a few day** in this sentence. 
I would like to express someone spend **more time** to fix the stuff.

Comment: Do you mean (1) the fix only lasted a few days (and then it broke down again), or (2) it took a few days to fix the computer completely, or (3) the friend was able to find a few days to work with you on your computer (and did all he/she could during those few days, but didn’t necessarily fix everything)?

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you for helping me to fix my computer **in** just a few
>   day**s**.

('for' would mean it was fixed temporarily)

However, you possibly want to make an accent on the time it took that person to help you:

> Thank you for all the days of your help in fixing my computer.